# How to keep track of time on how long user stay on a component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a service that keep track of time of how long the User is on a webpage.
One of the cases is that when user hit a refresh button (F5), the timer get reset. I solved this problem by storing the old timer onto the localstorage; so if a user hit refresh, it will retrieve the timer from localstorage.

However, there is one problem. When user log out and log back in, I want to start a new timer, not pulling out the old timer from the localstorage. How Do i start a new time when a user log out and log back in? I do not want it to pull the old timer from localstorage.

```
start() {
  this.startTime = localStorage.startTime ? JSON.parse(localStorage.startTime) : (new Date().getTime());
  localStorage.setItem('startTime', JSON.stringify(this.startTime));
}

getTime() {
  this.startTime = JSON.parse(localStorage.startTime);
  alert((this.startTime - (new Date().getTime())) / 1000);
}
```

Comment: `When user log out` Just clear localStorage on logout? Could also use sessionStorage

Comment: @CertainPerformance Not only log out, but when user exit the browser

Comment: Then say that in your question

Comment: @CertainPerformance also you cant assume user will always click log out. There are tiems when cookies r expired.

Answer (score 0):

> When user log out and log back in, I want to start a new timer, not pulling out the old timer from the localstorage. How Do i start a new time when a user log out and log back in

Do it in the `onNavigation` (or similarly named event / callback etc depending on how you are handling routing).